# Is it possible to use kvaser (can to USB) to read canopen device?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a SICK encoder which works with CANOPEN protocol and also I have a KVASER leaf light v2 CAN to USB interface. So my question is if there is a way to use KVASER to read CANOPEN device? Maybe with ROS_CANOPEN package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308591/is-it-possible-to-use-kvaser-(can-to-usb)-to-read-canopen-device?/) by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, ros_canopen utilizes SocketCAN package and many Kvaser CAN interfaces, such as Leaf Light v2, are supported by SocketCAN.
To install SocketCAN drivers for Kvaser hardware:

- Make sure you uninstalled linuxcan (CANlib), since Kvaser drivers blacklist SocketCAN modules:

  - $ cd linuxcan
    - $ sudo make uninstall
- Find your interface

  - ip a

Now you should see your Kvaser device listed, e.g.
- 3: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 10
link/can

For the rest, I suggest you to consult
https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/

---

Originally posted by [speloot](https://answers.ros.org/users/38740/speloot/) with karma: 46 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on 2018-11-29**:
Can you be specific? How should I do this?

**Comment by [speloot](https://answers.ros.org/users/38740/speloot/) on 2018-12-10**:
Just updated my previous response..

**Comment by [r.ghahremani](https://answers.ros.org/users/36906/r.ghahremani/) on 2018-12-10**:
@speloot, yup I found the answer pretty look like yours few days ago, was too busy to update here. After what you said, there is a configuration progress for ros canopen_chain_node after catching CAN data by ros socketcan_bridge.